# Which database fits better for a Gymlog app?

Tags: sql, flutter, dart, nosql, data-visualization

In my Gym Log App you can create an own gymplan. This plan will have a fix amount of exercises where you can note every day your stats for each exercise. Therefore every exercise can have 1-5 sets and every set have weight and reps. Im not sure whether a sql or nosql Database would fit better for this app.

One main thing the app should can is visualize the data like showing him the amount of reps he did with a weight over the time, so that the user can see his progress.

So in case of visualize data, is there a specific database which will fit better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it doesn't matter which one you choose. I did a similar app first with sqlite and then updated it to firebase. So choose whatever is easier of which one you want to learn.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you why you switched?

Comment: Well recently I've changed my phone and because of that I've lost all of my entries and had to start from the beginning, so I've moved everything to firebase so it won't happen again

Comment: Okay, is the swtich to another database easy possible or complicated? In case I want to switch later

Comment: I was following code with Andrea tutorial and courses so that made it easier for me and I highly recommend you to watch his tutorials and if you have some many buy his courses. You will learn much faster with him.